# How to use a file from Common Voice Corpus

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-to-text, speech

I downloaded the latest release of Mozilla's Common Voice. After unpacking the archive, I received a file of an unknown type. Who worked with this case? How do I get wav and txt files from it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I get the problem. For some unknown reason, instead of `ru.tar.gz` `ru.tar` is downloaded and everything breaks. If you add it `.gz` archive unpacks normally